# sql query takes time on a huge data

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to remove the duplicate entries in a table name `pincodecheck` but whenever I run the sql query in phpMyAdmin it keeps showing loading and nothing happens.

The table contains about 1,500,000 entries and so taking a small portion of the table to illustrate the problem.

The sql query that I am running:

```
DELETE FROM pincodecheck WHERE pinId NOT IN
(SELECT MIN(pinId) FROM (SELECT * FROM pincodecheck) AS tmpTable GROUP BY pincode)
```

The Table Structure

```
pinId   pincode deliveryStatus  divisionName    regionName  circleName  taluk   districtName stateName
146859  700031  Delivery        Calcutta South  Calcutta    West Bengal Kolkata Kolkata      WEST BENGAL
146860  700031  Delivery        Calcutta South  Calcutta    West Bengal Kolkata Kolkata      WEST BENGAL
146861  700031  Delivery        Calcutta South  Calcutta    West Bengal Kolkata Kolkata      WEST BENGAL
```

Comment: You tagged this question as both "mysql" and "sql-server". Which is it?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tag, I removed the sql-server tag.

Comment: `1,50,000` - This must be some new number formatting system.

Comment: @Alternatex That is the Indian Numbering System

Comment: @tsultan1990 Wow, [you were right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Numbering_System). You guys have your own numbering system..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holy nested SELECTs.

For starters remove the third nest. `DELETE FROM pincodecheck WHERE pinId NOT IN (SELECT min(pinID) from pincodecheck GROUP BY pincode)` should be fine.

If you are actually wanting to use a tmpTable to store the values while you are deleting from the same table, then actually insert into a tmp table and use that in the subquery. Simply using an alias isn't going to do anything.

You may want to stick `EXPLAIN` on the front of this query and see if you can discern any steps that may result in slowness from the return. My guess is that MySQL will execute the subquery first getting the min(PID) and then use that to DELETE FROM pincodecheck.

### Edited to add:

This could just be a case where it's going to take a very long time. If the results from `SELECT min(pinId) FROM pincodecheck GROUP BY pincode` are very large (I assume they since this is a deduping exercise) then it's going to take mysql a long time. It has to check each individual record in pincodecheck against what's returned from that query.

Perhaps... what you could do is write a query to get the final results that you want, and use that to insert into a new table, dropping the old table and then renaming the new table to take it's place. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE <newtable> AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        pincodecheck main
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (
                SELECT pincode, min(pinId) as minPinId
                FROM pincodecheck
                GROUP BY pincode
            ) sub ON
            main.pincode = sub.pincode and
            main.pinId = sub.MinPinId
    WHERE
        sub.pinCode IS NULL
```

Comment: The `pinId` is unique here, but `pincode` is not unique so I used `GROUP BY` to keep same values of pincode sequentially.

Comment: Ah! that makes sense. I will add the group by back in. I thought it was the same field... Sorry about that.

Comment: I have execute the query with the EXPLAIN in front and the rows returned in the PRIMARY query and the DEPENDANT query is absolutely ok.
I have also made a copy of the pincodecheck table and executed the following query : `DELETE FROM pincodecheck WHERE pinId NOT IN (SELECT MIN(pinId) FROM pincodecheck2 GROUP BY pincode) ` but still it is showing LOADING.

Comment: I just added some extra thoughts in the answer. You might have to fiddle with the `SELECT` in the `CREATE` statement, but it might be a quicker way of going about this.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. I only had to change `sub.pincode IS NULL` to `sub.pincode IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are trying to retain the MIN(pinId) for each unique pincode.

Try this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_pincode ON pincodecheck;
CREATE TABLE pincodecheck_new LIKE pincodecheck;
INSERT INTO pincodecheck_new SELECT MIN(pinId), pincode, deliveryStatus, divisionName, regionName, circleName  taluk, districtName, stateName FROM pincodecheck GROUP BY pincode, deliveryStatus, divisionName, regionName, circleName  taluk, districtName, stateName;
RENAME TABLE pincodecheck TO pincodecheck_old, pincodecheck_new TO pincodecheck;
```